# How to programmatically enable and disable mobile data Internet Connection in Ionic Framework

Tags: android, ionic-framework

My problem is simple. I need a way to turn on and off internet connection via mobile data using a button inside an Ionic app. Am I just missing something or is this even possible in Ionic Framework? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Diagnostic](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/diagnostic/) from ionic-native. From documentation `switchToMobileDataSettings()` serves your purpose. Take look into [cordova plugin](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin) repo for detailed information.

**Note**: This would still go through settings. I do not think there is a way to turn it on from an app button.

Comment: Cool! switchToMobileDataSettings() displays mobile settings. What about enabling data automatically?

Comment: ``Diagnostic`` handles all the device settings related actions. I havent come across any cordova/ionic plugin which can switch it on from the app. Havent come across many native apps which does this either.